# What governs the availability of trade goods?

Tags: victoria-2

I'm running into problems building up my navy because I don't seem to be able to  buy enough Clipper Convoys. In the trade screen it says *0.0 available for our country*. What causes this, and how can I make them available? More broadly, what governs the availability of goods to your country?

Answer (score 1):

Trade goods have to be actually produced by another country to be available to buy and they need to produce a surplus, as the first market they satisfy is the national one.

Additionally, the game has a priority order for selling/buying. The first country a nation trades with is the one, in whose sphere they are. Then other countries within the sphere and then finally it goes down the prestige ranking.

Clipper convoys are in high demand in the early game and in low supply later on, as they progressively get replaced by steamers. So unless you make them yourself or sphere a big clipper producer, they are very hard to acquire.
Try to secure one of those (you can check the top producers on the trade screen) or build a clipper shipyard yourself.

Source: http://www.victoria2wiki.com/Trade